# How to apply condtion in copying a file in the same document libaray in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to copy a selected file in the same document library in sharepoint online using csom. I have used below code and it work

```
// get the file
                File file = sourceItem.File;
                clientContext.Load(file);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                char[] chars = { '.' };
                var fileName = file.Name.Split(chars);
                // build destination url
                string locationUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + destinationList.Title + "/" + fileName[0] + "-Copy." + fileName[1];

                // read the file, copy the content to new file at new location
                file.CopyTo(locationUrl, true);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();`
```

It copies all the fields in the new item generated. How do I apply condition and skip specific fields so as to not update and have them blank.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than copy the file, you can add the new document to the Document Library with the existing one by disabling the Overwrite property.

```
    //Prepare to upload
    Boolean replaceExisting = false;
    String fileName = file.Url;
    FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);

    // Upload document
    SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExisting);
```

myLibrary.Update();

Comment: Seems the above code doesn't work for sharepoint online. I need csom code.

Comment: As I told, Please try to add the document rather than copying it. Refer the link below [link](https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2009/04/working-with-documents-stored-in-sharepoint-document-library-programmatically/)

Comment: What error did you got? Please let me know

Comment: it seems for server side.

Comment: Change the server side to client side. It is very simple. Replace SPFile to FIle. Thats it

Comment: myLibrary s the name of my currentlist/ libraray, that I get at runtime from url. "myLibrary.Files" gives error, mylibraray doesnot have .file

Comment: You can declare your Library as a folder. **Folder myLibrary = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("FolderUrl");** PLease try this